# Mixin animation takes 1 argument but 2 were passed

Tags: css, animation, sass

I have the bellow sass code ,

```
@include animation(swayb $speed ease infinite 3s, reset 1s ease forwards 5s);
```

If i watch using `compass watch` from my ubuntu machine it will throws an error,

> (Line 2500 of _includes/_common.scss: Mixin animation takes 1 argument
>   but 2 were passed.)

Comment: Might be you are defined 1 argument in animation function but here while using you are passing more then 1 argument which causing this error.

Comment: But this code is working fine some other machines

Comment: can you pass arguments with extra function brackets like +transition-duration((0.2s, 0.5s, 0.2s)).




https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/575

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will work. Check below code :-

@include animation((swayb $speed ease infinite 3s, reset 1s ease forwards 5s));

reference - https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/699

and please check this article also

https://www.sitepoint.com/sass-multiple-arguments-lists-or-arglist/